# Login form doesn't read sha512

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sha512

I added `sha512` to this login form but I keep getting the error Invalid username or password.
I used http://www.convertstring.com/Hash/SHA512 to set the password in the database

Why doesn't it work? The password in the database is hashed with sha512 + salt but i keep getting the error that the username/password is incorect.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $password1 = ($_POST['password_']);
    $salted = "b5vy2m92m9c5my925myic52ddqwm534itkic4m3timcy35".$password1;
    $hashed = hash('sha512', $salted);

    if(!$_POST['username_'] || !$hashed) {

        echo '<div class="alert alert-block alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i></button>Complete all fields.</div>';    
    } else {    
        $q = Config::$g_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` = ? AND `password` = ?');    
        $q->execute(array($_POST['username_'], $hashed));
```

Login form

```
<input type="text" name="username_"/><br/>
<input type="password" name="password_"/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="login" class="btn btn-inverse">
```

Total script:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) echo '<script> 
    location.replace("'.Config::$_PAGE_URL.'"); </script>'
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$password1 = ($_POST['password_']);
$salted = "b5vy2m92m9c5my925myic52ddqwm534itkic4m3timcy35".$password1;
$hashed = hash('sha512', $salted);    
if(!$_POST['username_'] || !$hashed) {    
        echo '<div class="alert alert-block alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i></button>Complete all fields.</div>';    
    } else {    
        $q = Config::$g_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` = ? AND `password` = ?');
        $q->execute(array($_POST['username_'], $hashed));    
        if($q->rowCount()) {
            $d = Config::$g_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM `panel_restrict` WHERE `PlayerName` = ?');    
            $d->execute(array($_POST['username_']));    
            $row1 = $d->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);    
            if($d->rowCount() && date("Y-m-d H:i:s") <= gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $row1->Time)) { 
                if($row1->Permanent == 1)   {    
                    $expira = "<b>permanent</b>";    
                } else {    
                    $expira = "pana la data de <b>". gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $row1->Time) ."</b>";    
                }    
                echo '<div class="alert alert-block alert-danger">    
                Contul tau este suspendat '.$expira.'.<br />    
                Motiv: <b>'.$row1->Reason.'</b><br />    
                Banat pe data de <b>'.$row1->BanTimeDate.'</b></div>';    
            } else {                        
                $dele = Config::$g_con->prepare("DELETE FROM panel_restrict WHERE PlayerName = ?");    
                $dele->execute(array($_POST['username_']));    
                $row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);    
                $_SESSION['user'] = $row->id;
                echo '<script> location.replace("'.Config::$_PAGE_URL.'"); </script>';    
                //setcookie ("user",$_POST['username_'],time()+3600*24*60);    
                //setcookie ("password",$_POST['password_'],time()+3600*24*60);    
                //header ('Location: ' . $_PAGE_URL);
            }
        }
        else echo '<div class="alert alert-block alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i></button>Invalid username or password.</div>';    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Start over then user `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` read the manual

Comment: what type of field for password in database?

Comment: I'm using  varchar(256) for the password and  varchar(64) for the username

Comment: For someone to strictly answer your original question, they'll need a copy of the hash you received from that website.  That said, I'm with @MasivuyeCokile - I'd personally rethink your entire approach to handling the passwords.  There's 3 huge advantages to password_*() functions: 1. They handle salting for you, 2. They're extremely well tested, 3. If implemented correctly, they'll self-update over time as PHP releases stronger algorithms.  On that last point, I'd look at using something computationally harder than a simple SHA512 too... (google for bcrypt for an example).

Comment: stop telling to use something better... even if i would you bcrypt you would say use something better, help me fix this problem please..

Answer (score 0):

> stop telling to use something better... even if i would you bcrypt you
>   would say use something better, help me fix this problem please..

No. People are telling you to use *password_hash()* and *password_verify()* for very good reasons. Use them. It will save you a tremendous amount of work and more importantly, will hopefully stop you from implementing a half-baked solution by yourself. You should **not** create your own salt. In fact, it has been deprecated as of PHP 7.

Now, to answer your question. When you used the online tool to generate your hash you inputted a salt. This **online tool *prepended*** the salt to your password. **You are *appending* it** to your password. In addition to that, I think the case from the **online tool is UPPERCASING** your hash while **PHP leaves it lowercase**. You need to compare the same cases.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b3801209519783618445a06d31380b24b876fd4c

All this to say, that yes, using *password_hash()* and *password_verify()* makes your life easier. http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php